# Accessing AdditionalContext of RequestSecurityToken from inside UserNameSecurityTokenHandler

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I am creating a custom STS using a custom UserNameSecurityTokenHandler derived class.  In the client, I am adding some additional information to the AdditionalContext property of the RequestSecurityToken that the Token Handler needs to fully authenticate (in addition to User Name & Password).

I assume that the RequestSecurityToken must be available to me somewhere in my Token Handler, but I cannot locate it.  I've prowled through the code with Reflector, but that has not helped either.

How can I get at this information?

Thanks in advance.

David Mullin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was confusing two unrelated things.  The UserNameSecurityTokenHandler class is for authenticating the UserName/Password Client Credentials, which then flows into the STS as the "Current Principal".

So, never mind.