# Two Custom UserNameSecurityTokenHandlers

Tags: validation, security, passwords, handler, wif

I have WIF STS with сustom UserNameSecurityTokenHandler. It works fine, UserNameSecurityToken passed to Validate method of UserNameSecurityTokenHandler. But I want use **two different u\p validations** on one STS. Is this possible?

For example we have user and workstation clients and want to validate these passwords by different rules.

There are no additional context found inside [UserNameSecurityTokenHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782963/accessing-additionalcontext-of-requestsecuritytoken-from-inside-usernamesecurity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only register one token handler per token type.

Comment: WIF’s token handler collection will, by default, contain only one token handler for each token type. There is a one-to-one relationship between token handlers and token types.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517261.aspx